# Armazenar ip de usuário ao entrar no site

Tags: php, html, ip

Quero exibir um video de boas vindas em meu site somente quando for a primeira vez que o usuario entrar no meu site, eu pensei em usar o seguinte código:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Ele me retorna o ip do usuário e assim eu iria armazenar no banco de dados e toda vez que alguem entra no site irá fazer uma busca se já teve esse ip, senão exibe o video, mas essa seria a forma correta? Com o tempo a busca seria muito lenta e pesada? Como posso resolver da melhor forma caso essa não for a mais viável?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para evitar tráfego desnecessário eu faria isso com COOKIEs, também por que o visitante pode trocar de IP se mudar do provedor de internet dele:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime']))
{
    setcookie("firsttime", "no", /* EXPIRE */);
    /* Coloque aqui o conteúdo da primeira visita */
}
else
{
    /* OPCIONAL: Coloque aqui conteúdo pras visitas
    seguintes  do mesmo usuário*/
}
?>
```

Você pode fazer isso por JAVASCRIPT também e usar COOKIES ou LOCALSTORAGE.

Agora se você quiser realmente registrar os IPs, você deverá criar um amarzenamento, no caso aconselho JSON, e ao acessar o PHP irá consultar todos os ITENS em ARRAY dentro do JSON e se não encontrar o IP na lista ele irá apresentar o vídeo.

```
{"IP_Visitantes":["202.1.x.x","187.2.x.x","190.4.x.x","66.8.x.x",]}
```